# Unable to understand iOS core graphics coordinate system transformation, need assistance

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am trying to understand quartz 2d coordinate system, Currently I am reading Apple reference guide and old book "Quartz 2d graphics for mac os x developer".

I understand the concept of user-space and device-space concept that device-space can have different default coordinate system and device-space coordinates can't be modified, and we map user-space by modifying its coordinate system acceding to device-space to achieve desire result.

---

- First part of the problem

---

Quartz 2d graphics for mac os x developer book says:

> When transforming a coordinate system, **you must have another
>   coordinate system to compare it to. The transformation provides a
>   relative mapping from one coordinate system to the other. When you
>   draw in the transformed coordinate system, the transformation maps the
>   graphic back to the first coordinate system**. The appearance of that
>   graphic in the fixed coordinate system is affected by the
>   transformation.

i didn't get this point in bold.

And

[Quartz 2D programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-CJBBAEEC) says:

> Quartz accomplishes device independence with a separate coordinate
>   system—user space—mapping it to the coordinate system of the output
>   device—device space—using the current transformation matrix, or CTM. A
>   matrix is a mathematical construct used to efficiently describe a set
>   of related equations. The current transformation matrix is a
>   particular type of matrix called an affine transform, which maps
>   points from one coordinate space to another by applying translation,
>   rotation, and scaling operations (calculations that move, rotate, and
>   resize a coordinate system).
>
> The current transformation matrix has a secondary purpose: It allows
>   you to transform how objects are drawn. For example, to draw a box
>   rotated by 45 degrees, you rotate the coordinate system of the page
>   (the CTM) before you draw the box. **Quartz draws to the output device
>   using the rotated coordinate system.**

Confusion is that "Quartz draws to the output device using the rotated coordinate system.", if I want to draw one object(image etc) rotated and other with out rotation then what happen? We have whole coordinates rotated every thing will be drawn is rotated?

I am trying different experiments but unable to wrap my head around this, I create an image my drawing two line replicating bottom left coordinate system in photoshop and then added to my project to see visibly how coordinates are behaving by calling `CGContextRotateCTM(myContext, 45);` in drawrect method, but it didn't do any thing to image which I included in xib file using interface builder placing image inside uiimage.

this code is from quartz 2D programming guide

```
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect contextRect = self.bounds;

CGContextTranslateCTM(myContext, 0, contextRect.size.height);
CGContextRotateCTM(myContext, 45); //my modification
CGContextScaleCTM(myContext, 1, -1);

float w, h;
w = contextRect.size.width;
h = contextRect.size.height;

CGAffineTransform myTextTransform;
CGContextSelectFont (myContext, "Helvetica-Bold", h/10, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (myContext, 10);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (myContext, kCGTextFillStroke);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 1, 0, .5);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, 1);
myTextTransform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
CGContextSetTextMatrix (myContext, myTextTransform);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (myContext, 0, 50, "Quartz 2D", 9);
```

but this code is modifying the text drawn on screen not the image I added?

---

- Second Part of the problem

---

This is also from Quartz 2D programming guide:

> ... apply a transform that translates the origin to the upper-left
>   corner of the PDF context and scales the y-coordinate by -1.
>
> Using a scaling transform to negate the y-coordinate alters some
>   conventions in Quartz drawing. For example, if you call
>   CGContextDrawImage to draw an image into the context, the image is
>   modified by the transform when it is drawn into the destination. ...

I am already doing this -1 thing but no effect on image and this -1 thing is still not clear to me.

I have read this document several times, tried searching on google but no useful tutorial and also no latest books are available only books written in 2004, 2005, 2006. Can any one help regarding this or can refer me useful resources to learn this in depth.

Desperately waiting for replies, really need help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this guide and I hope all your problems will be clear

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html

Comment: thats exactly what i want it cleared my concepts. Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UIImageView subclass and overriding drawRect? This is not supported (see the docs) and is probably why your image is unaffected by any transformations.

If you want to do a lot of transformations and bespoke drawing code then you should be using a UIView subclass and drawing your image manually using CGContextDrawImage()

Any transforms are applied to drawing operations done after the transform. You will see code samples in the docs where the graphics state is saved, a transform applied, some drawing done, and then the context is restored. This is how you draw some components rotated and some not.

Hopefully the second part of your question will become clear once you are drawing your image via CG code and not via an image view.

Comment: i am using uiview subclass and in its drawrect i am writing all the code. just want to see visibly behaviour of coordinates and transformation that why i add the image drawn two line presenting bottom left coordinates which is quartz 2d default. In xib file i put that image in uiimage. I modify this view not uiimage with the subclass in which i am doing all the code, so the whole view is a subclass of draw2d class which i created. thanks for reply.

Comment: What do you mean by "in xib file i put the image in UIImage"? I read this is you question as you making a uiimageview, since you can't create a UIImage in a xib file. I don't understand how you've set this up, can you put some screenshots in your question?

Comment: i draged and dropped the uiimageview and in that i set the coordinate image and didn't do any thing else, after doing this and writing the transform code all i was expecting that image will also rotate and i will be visibly seeing where the coordinates are now, so i can understand code much easily.